# Loop for comparing all the objects of two lists

Tags: java, android, json, db4o

I'm receiving two object's List and I should compare all the objects...

For this I've been using the next loop:

```
        for (int i=0;it2.hasNext();i++ ) {
           objetoDb4o=it2.next();
           tratdb4o=(Tratam)objetoDb4o;
             for (int j=0;it.hasNext();j++ ) {
                    objetoJson = it.next();
                    tratJson = (Tratam)objetoJson;

            }
        }
```

it and it2 are iterators.. The values of size are correct (4 and 4)

But the loop doesn't work.. the first for iterates only one time, and the second for iterates three times.

I can not find the mistake! Can you help me please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the iterator `it` before you enter the inner loop, otherwise you'll go through the second list only once during the first iteration of the outer loop; the remaining iterations will stop at `it.hasNext()`, skipping the inner loop altogether.

Comment: And.. how can I reset the iterator? Do not miss his values?

Comment: @HéctorOrtiz By resetting I mean getting the iterator again from the same collection from which you've gotten it originally. For example, if you got it by calling `iterator()` method on a list, re-assign the `it` by calling `myList.iterator()` again inside the loop. The best thing to do is to declare `it` inside the loop as well. This way the initialization will happen on each iteration.